# SQL Server: datetime out of range error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query

```
SELECT W.NUMBER,B.NAME,Br.NAME,W.WDATE,W.REPAIRSTATUS,W.REPAIRCOST,W.REMARK
FROM Work_Order AS W,Brands AS B,Branches AS Br
WHERE W.BRANDID = B.ID AND W.BRANCHID = Br.ID
AND CAST(WDATE as DATETIME)  < CAST('09/18/2012' AS DATETIME)
```

and the system respond with

> *The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.*

also using this query it gives the same error

```
SELECT W.NUMBER,B.NAME,Br.NAME,W.WDATE,W.REPAIRSTATUS,W.REPAIRCOST,W.REMARK
FROM Work_Order AS W,Brands AS B,Branches AS Br
WHERE W.BRANDID = B.ID AND W.BRANCHID = Br.ID
ORDER BY CAST(W.WDATE AS DATETIME)
```

WDATE is like '09/03/2012' and it is an input from jquery ui datepicker with mm/dd/yyyy date format

Please help me I don't know how to fix it.

I am working on SQL Server 2005.

EDIT: I tried the same queries with another sql server 2005 and it's working fine so please how to fix this error with a sql server settings ??

Comment: Which one throws the error? `CAST(WDATE as DATETIME)` or `CAST('09/09/2012' AS DATETIME)`? And what's the value of `W.WDATE`?

Comment: check WDATE..what is its value?

Comment: CAST('09/09/2012' AS DATETIME)

Comment: Try to phrase this date literal in a language-neutral manner i.e. `CAST('20120909' AS DATETIME)`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I did and the same error !!

Comment: it shouldn't give error...i am getting "2012-09-09 00:00:00.000" value when i tried it...Check  WDATE instead..

Comment: WDATE  is varchar and I am casting it to datetime value

Comment: See and embrace: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: yes and that might be the cause of problem..you may be having value which is giving exception..

Comment: @AhmedKato please post some of the data from `WDATE` so we can see the format it is in.

Comment: Id suggest you need to append the time to the date, so it reads "09/09/2012 00:00:00" although I would also suggest it should be "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" as I ran into similar issues with some queries

Comment: @AhmedKato a few things to test, if you remove the data filter from the `WHERE` clause does the query work?  If you add the `CAST(WDATE as DATETIME)` to the `SELECT` does it `CAST()` the value?  I would focus on getting the date conversion to work first before adding it to a query.

Comment: EDIT: I tried the same queries with another sql server 2005 and it's working fine so please how to fix this error with a sql server settings ??

Comment: @AhmedKato - Ambiguous date formats are interpreted according to the default language of your login. Maybe that is different between the two servers. Though you should use appropriate data types to avoid this sort of issue anyway.

Comment: Check if one of the values in Work_Order.WDATE is not an invalid date format: Select CAST(WDATE as DATETIME) from Work_Order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your WDATE is a varchar / char and not datatime as it should be, you can cast it like this, however i recommand that you change the datatype to datetime.
Try this:

```
SELECT W.NUMBER,B.NAME,Br.NAME,W.WDATE,W.REPAIRSTATUS,W.REPAIRCOST,W.REMARK 
FROM Work_Order AS W,Brands AS B,Branches AS Br 
WHERE W.BRANDID = B.ID AND W.BRANCHID = Br.ID 
AND CONVERT( DATETIME, WDATE, 101) < CONVERT( DATETIME, '09/18/2012', 101)
```

Try this code, it should find most of the invalid dates

```
SELECT WDATE, W.NUMBER,B.NAME,Br.NAME,W.WDATE,W.REPAIRSTATUS,W.REPAIRCOST,W.REMARK 
FROM Work_Order AS W,Brands AS B,Branches AS Br 
WHERE W.BRANDID = B.ID AND W.BRANCHID = Br.ID 
AND WDATE not like '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/20[0-1][0-9]'
```

Comment: EDIT: I tried the same queries with another sql server 2005 and it's working fine so please how to fix this error with a sql server settings ??

Comment: @AhmedKato using char to store a datetime causes problems. I think you have at 1 or more row that can't be converted to that format. Am trying to create a script to locate those rows

Comment: even if their is no data it gives me the same error !! I think something is wrong with the server itself

Comment: @AhmedKato is one of your "tables" a view ? Try selecting from the views. If that doesn't work, check if you have computed columns. Those could also cause the problem

Comment: NO their is no views...and your query is giving me some tuples that are not stored in the database !!!!! some date fields are empty and I don't have empty date fields also numbers are not correct

Comment: @AhmedKato I truely doubt my query will return data that does not exist in the database. if my second query gave you rows, I would take a good look at those rows. Those will be the cause of your conversion errors.