# How to convert this Varchar to date

Tags: sql

can you please help me how to convert these varchar to date

```
20151001 to 2015-10-01
12200106 to 1220-01-06
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you using ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20151001')
```

The following will convert the data you provided. Check out [this link](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp) for more information to help you understand the different date functions.

And if you get an error for: Out of range: check out the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511447/sql-server-datetime-out-of-range-error)

Answer (score 0):

For sql server 2008+ you can use the [**`date`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) or [**`datetime2`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)data type to support years from `'0001-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`

```
select convert(date,'20151001') as dt
union all
select convert(date,'12200106')
```

returns

```
+------------+
|     dt     |
+------------+
| 2015-10-01 |
| 1220-01-06 |
+------------+
```